# Wrap several elements in Story Board Xcode 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I'm working with Story Board in Xcode 6, I'm creating a Form with 10 Labels and for each label one Text Field.

Label 1: __________________

Label 2: __________________

Label 3: __________________

....

I want to wrap this elements in only one element, for work in the easy way to center in the View Controller.

The is question... is possible transform this group in only one?

Comment: Short and sweet one - UITableView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select all your labels, then `Editor > Embed in > View`. This will create a new view and put all the selected views as subviews. Another option is using an [IBOutletCollection](http://nshipster.com/ibaction-iboutlet-iboutletcollection/).

Oh, and looks like I've overseen the exact issue, Kampai is right, I'm pretty sure UITableView suits here very well.